# Parsing poorly written CSV (both tabs and spaces) with Python

Tags: python, parsing, csv

So I wrote a script that downloads a file, saves the file, then reads through the file and stores the values in variables which I can further use. My issue is that the original file is not very well formed. I thought originally that it was tab delimited however there appears to be some excess spaces as well.

Here's a subset of my code:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('emailLogins_20130930')):
    parsedURL = str(link.get('href')).strip()
    fileURL = 'https://xxxxx.com'+parsedURL
    request = opener.open(fileURL)
    out = open(fileName, 'a')

    for row in request:
        if re.search('Source', row): #strip out the header on the original file before rewriting the file to disk
            continue
        else:
            if row.strip():
                for column in row:
                    out.write(column)
            else:
                continue
    out.close()
    time.sleep(4)


#This part removes some null lines (if they exist) I found previously in the files  
with open(fileName, 'rb') as f_origin:
    data = f_origin.read()

with open('cleanCSV.csv', 'wb') as f_clean: 
    f_clean.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))

#Attempting to remove the tabs and replace with commas.  My thought was that the spaces would just be included in the strings
#but it looks as though those are being converted to ',' as well.

in_txt = csv.reader(open('cleanCSV.csv', 'rb'), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open('new-csv-test.csv', 'wb'))
out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

filereader = open('new-csv-test.csv', 'rb')

reader = csv.reader(filereader, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

for row in reader:
    rowlist = list(row)
    source = rowlist[0]
    print '0: ' + source
    #start_date = rowlist[1]
    #print '1: ' + start_date
    #start_time = rowlist[2]
    #print '2: ' + start_time
    #start = start_date + ' ' + start_time
    #print 'START: ' + start
    start = rowlist[1]
    print '1: ' + rowlist[1]
    start_dt = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    start_ts = start_ts = start_dt.strftime('%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
    upstreamIP = rowlist[2]
    print '2: ' + upstreamIP
    username = rowlist[3]
    print '3: ' + username
    emailLogins = rowlist[4]
    print '4: ' + emailLogins
    emailProvider = rowlist[5]
    print '5: ' + emailProvider + '\n'

    mergedEmail = emailLogins+'@'+emailProvider
```

Here's an example of the original file:

```
11.111.111.111_vpn_ 2013-09-29 19:50:35     NULL    Pxxx    aol.com
11.111.111.111_vpn_ 2013-09-29 19:49:50     NULL    Dxxxxxxx    aol.com
11.111.111.111_vpn_ 2013-09-29 19:54:24     NULL    fxxxxxxx_governmentgrant    aol.com
11.111.111.111_vpn__parsed  2013-09-30 10:58:48 98506   mxxxxx05    hxxxxxyen   yahoo.com
mace3_vpn_11.11.111.111     2013-09-30 11:14:48     NULL    mxxxxxys00  aol.com
11.111.111.111_vpn__parsed  2013-09-30 11:10:08 98506   mxxxxx05    hhxxxxxen   yahoo.com
mace3_vpn_111.111.111.1     2013-09-30 11:38:57     NULL    Fndxxxxxa   aol.com
mace3_vpn_11.11.111.111     2013-09-30 11:24:49     NULL    myxxxxxx00  aol.com
mace3_vpn_11.11.111.111     2013-09-30 11:25:16     NULL    mxxxxxxxxxx01   yahoo.com
```

Here's what my code is doing (note the double ',' after the first column. I expect the second set of double ',' since there is often times a column with no data.

```
111.111.111.1_vpn_,2013-09-29 19:50:35,,NULL,Pxxxx0,aol.com
111.111.111.1_vpn_,2013-09-29 19:49:50,,NULL,Dxxxxxen,aol.com
111.111.111.1_vpn_,2013-09-29 19:54:24,,NULL,fxxxxxxk_governmentgrant,aol.com
111.111.111.1_vpn__parsed,2013-09-30 10:58:48,98506,mxxxxxx5,hxxxxxxen,yahoo.com
mace3_vpn_111.111.111.1,,2013-09-30 11:14:48,,NULL,mxxxxxxs00,aol.com
111.111.111.1_vpn__parsed,2013-09-30 11:10:08,98506,mxxxxxx5,hxxxxxxen,yahoo.com
mace3_vpn_111.111.111.1,,2013-09-30 11:38:57,,NULL,Fxxxxxxxa,aol.com
mace3_vpn_111.111.111.1,,2013-09-30 11:24:49,,NULL,mxxxxxxs00,aol.com
mace3_vpn_111.111.111.1,,2013-09-30 11:25:16,,NULL,mxxxxxxxxx1,yahoo.com
```

I went back and looked at the original file in VI to see the ASCII value of the whitespace between the first column and the second column on the second rows and it appears to have two tabs instead of a space and a tab.  Not sure how to remove the extra tab here but leave the extra tab which should show up when a column has no data.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Is it possible for the input file to contain empty fields? If not, you could simply preprocess it and replace any run of whitespace with a single tab. Otherwise, I'm not sure how you can distinguish between incorrect whitespace and a legitimate empty field.

Comment: I thought that all fields were separated by a tab initially however it appears that some fields may actually be separated by a space and a tab or something similar that is making python believe that it should be converted to a comma.  By leaving in two commas where there shouldn't it throws my variables off when I believe to process each line.

Comment: Also yes it is possible for the date field to have a legitimate space.  I also tried to convert all spaces to a comma but ran into the same situation where there was a space and a comma with having two commas inserted which caused the parsing of the csv to freak out thinking there's more than one field where there isn't.